# Describe baseline and expand deliver and rebase activities

Tags: clearcase, cleartool, clearcase-ucm

I need to list all of the activities delivered in a baseline but need any deliver and rebase activities expanded.

I have tried a script to read the lines and do an "lsact -contrib" but some of the deliveries contain nested deliveries and I have become confused. It would be useful if I could also have the date of the activity as well.

I have tried experimenting with "-fmt"  but with disappointing results.

The reason is that the management want to identify all activities in a baseline that contain a keyword. Currently this fails if the activity is part of a deliver oporation.

Has anyone come across a simliar requirement and if so how have they resolved it?

IBM have come up with big fat Zero, so I am looking to you gurus and wizards to give me inspiration.

Answer (score 2):

No I didn't see that kind of requirement before.

Note that if an activity is part of a deliver, you will end up with a "deliver.xxx" activity in the destination Stream, with only *one* comment associated with that deliver (losing all the comments associated with the initial activities delivered)

So you need indeed to use `lsact -contrib`, following the technote "[swg21136012: Activities delivered since the last baseline](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21136012)"

> run the following command to determine what activities have been delivered since the baselines creation:

```
%> cleartool diffbl -activities baseline:REL1.3.117 stream:integration_stream@/vobstore/pvob deliver.development_steam.20010824.08050

>> deliver.development_steam.20010824.080503 "deliver development_steam on 08/24/01 08:05:03."
>> deliver.development_steam.20010824.080802 "deliver development_steam on 08/24/01 08:08:02."
>> ...
```

> The above output will display the integration activities associated with the deliver operations to that stream.
>
> **If you would like to obtain a list of contributing activities for the associated integration activities, the following command can be issued for each integration activity respectively**:
>
> Example:

```
%> cleartool lsact -contrib activity:deliver.development_steam.20010824.080503@/vobstore/pvob
```

Combining that with **[`fmt_ccase`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm)** (the `-fmt` option you mentioned) will allow you, for each activity, to display only what is of interest (the Activity id and its comment, in order to grep for your keyword).