# How do I search ClearCase for an activity to determine if it's been delivered?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool, clearquest

We use a combination of ClearQuest and ClearCase for code versioning.  We have several activities in FixComplete, but some have been delivered and some have not.  We would like to find the activities that have been delivered, and move them to Closed.  Is there a way to use cleartool to search for a specific activity ID and see if it's been delivered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each deliver baseline, you can list the list of contributing activities, in order to see which one were part of the deliver.
See "[Describe baseline and expand deliver and rebase activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327917/describe-baseline-and-expand-deliver-and-rebase-activities)".

That won't be a definitive answer though because you could have reused one of those activity for an additional checkin *after* the deliver.

However, if you do that check (describing of the delivered activity, and listing of the *contributing* activities), you can close those activities by closing their associated ClearQuest items. That will prevent reusing that activity for a checkin.