# Finding which developer activities were delivered in a specific delivery

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

In ClearCase, how do I find which developer activities were delivered in a specific delivery?

Doing

> lscat -long

On either activity doesn't reveal this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`lsact` (`cleartool lsactivity`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769786/vendor-branches-in-git):

> List activities or baselines that contributed to the change set of an integration activity:

```
lsact/ivity -contrib activity-selector [...]
```

The activity selector must be:

```
activity:anActivityName@\aPVob      # Windows
activity:anActivityName@/vobs/aPVob # Unix
```

A deliver activity would be named "`deliver.xxx`", and is the name of nthe activity recording all files modified during the deliver.

[image: deliverss]

That will allow you to find back "`Activity1`" in the diagram above for the first deliver.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327917/describe-baseline-and-expand-deliver-and-rebase-activities for a concrete example of delivery activities.

Comment: When I asked this question, I told people in my team that there's a guy called VonC on Stack Overflow and that I'm willing to bet any amount that he'll be the one to answer my question. You've answered many questions from me over the past few years, and I just wanted to say - Thank you so much!

Comment: @AmirRachum You are welcome. I am here every day. (and I mean: every.single.day: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122976/anyone-with-a-visited-1000-days-1000-consecutive-in-his-her-profile)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
cleartool lsact -contrib activity-name
```

while `activity-name` is a delivery activity