# Relating baselines from parent stream to those in a child stream

Tags: clearcase

Suppose you make a baseline in a child stream (e.g. release), name it **baseline_rel_X** and then at the same time you deliver the changes to the parent stream (e.g. integration) and also make a baseline there called **baseline_int_Y**.  At that point, the baselines baseline_rel_X and baseline_int_Y are effectively the same (notwithstanding different streams, each element will be the same if compared).

Is there a way to relate (establish equality) between a baseline in the parent stream and its corresponding baseline in a child stream, in this example relate **baseline_rel_X** to **baseline_int_Y**, given that their names are different?

The reason we want to do this is to help us list all the files to be deployed to PROD, which corresponds to the parent (integration) stream above.  We make many baselines in our child (release) stream, which corresponds to our TEST/UAT environment, until we collect enough changes to make one in the integration stream, which goes into PROD.  You could say that there is a one-to-many relationship between baselines in PROD and TEST/UAT.  So we want to take the integration baseline that is currently in PROD, **relate it to its original baseline in the release stream (that unfortunately has a different name)**, and then do a diff between that and the most recent baseline to list all the changes we've made since we last released to PROD.

I know this sounds confusing but I am hoping it makes some sense.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to:

- do some complex or long `cleartool diffbl`
- rely on a naming convention you cannot change

I would [record in an **attribute**](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkattr.htm) the name of the baseline form which you did the deliver (`baseline_rel_X`) into the object `baseline:baseline_int_Y@\pvob`.

Other ways would be:

- seek a baseline in rel which would be close enough of the [deliver activity name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9328314/6309) (named after the stream and the deliver date): that is quite imprecise.
- look for the hyperlink which should exist between the source and the destination baseline. Again, a bit complex.

Comment: amazing how such a complex product is lacking such a basic feature ...  i am disappointed.  thanks for your answer though

Comment: @foampile I agree. UCM is an layer added on top of an existing (and quite old) product, and while the ideas are interesting, the implementation is... lacking.

Comment: I know many projects in ClearCase that use a naming convention for that purpose.